# How to replace row if primary key already exists ("IntegrityError: duplicate key value")

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

I'm using psycopg2 to insert data into a PostgreSQL table.
I'd like to force the SQL query to overwrite/replace an existing row in case that row already exists (i.e. the new row has a primary key identical to an existing one).

So far I wrote a script that contains some inputs in a JS object, where `col1` is the primary key:

```
myInputs = {'tablename': 'november', 'col1': 1, 'col2': 0.1, 'col3': 60}
```

The executed SQL (using psycopg2's cursor.execute) is the following:

```
"""INSERT INTO myschema.p{} (  col1,
                               col2,     
                               col3 
                                    ) 
             VALUES         (  {},
                               {},
                               {}   )""".format(
                                               myInputs ["tablename"],
                                               myInputs ["col1"],
                                               myInputs ["col2"],
                                               myInputs ["col3"]                                         
                           )
```

If I run the SQL command with a second set of inputs containing a similar primary key `col1`, e.g.

```
myInputs2 = {'tablename': 'november', 'col1': 1, 'col2': 10, 'col3': 20}
```

, I get the following error:

```
psycopg2.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pnovember_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (col1)=(1) already exists.
```

What would be a proper way to handle this error and achieve this automatic row replacement? I've never used it, but would the best approach be to use the `EXCEPTION` clause described [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html)?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT

Comment: Just a suggestion, first delete the record based on matching key and then insert.